# django can't find new sqlite version? (SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found 3.7.17))

Tags: python, django, sqlite, centos7

I've cloned a django project to a Centos 7 vps and I'm trying to run it now, but I get this error when trying to `migrate`:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found 3.7.17).
```

When I checked the version for sqlite, it was 3.7.17, so I downloaded the newest version from sqlite website and replaced it with the old one, and now when I version it, it gives:

```
$ sqlite3 --version
3.27.2 2019-02-25 16:06:06 bd49a8271d650fa89e446b42e513b595a717b9212c91dd384aab871fc1d0f6d7
```

Still when I try to migrate the project, I get the exact same message as before which means the newer version is not found. I'm new to linux and would appreciate any help.

Comment: The version of the standalone sqlite3 executable is irrelevant, it's the version of the Python library that is important.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Oh. So then how can I update that? I tried `pip install pysqlite` and it installed it, but since I have python 3, it complained: >pysqlite is not supported on Python 3. When using Python 3, use the sqlite3 module from the standard library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImproperlyConfigured('SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found %s).' % Database.sqlite\_version)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60826836/improperlyconfiguredsqlite-3-8-3-or-later-is-required-found-s-database)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To check which version of SQLite Python is using:

```
$ python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 12 2019, 16:23:13) 
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.27.2'
```

For me the new version of sqlite3 is in /usr/local/bin so I had to recompile Python, telling it to look there:

```
sudo LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib make altinstall
```

Comment: how exactly is this done? i have a python3.7.7 installation and the sqlite version running is 3.7.17.

Answer (score 68):

I got the same error in [CentOS 7.6](https://lwn.net/Articles/773680/) and [Python 3.7.3](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-373/) versions. I think you are using [Django 2.2.*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/) some version. In latest of [Django 2.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/), they changed the [SQLIte](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) version, that cause of your problem.

This is the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.2/#django-2-2-release-notes) of [Django 2.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/) about [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html).

> The minimum supported version of SQLite is increased from 3.7.15 to 3.8.3.

So I found 3 steps to solve this problem,

---

- **Downgrade Django Version**

So you can install latest version of [Django 2.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/) by using this command, which mean you're going to downgrade your `Django` version.

```
pip install Django==2.1.*
```

---

- **[Upgrading SQLite on CentOS to 3.8.3 or Later](https://number1.co.za/upgrading-sqlite-on-centos-to-3-8-3-or-later/)**

or you can followup below steps as well to keep the latest version `Django`. I directly get the steps from [Upgrading SQLite on CentOS to 3.8.3 or Later](https://number1.co.za/upgrading-sqlite-on-centos-to-3-8-3-or-later/) article.

You can download the latest `sqlite` version from [here](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html).

```sh
wget https://www.sqlite.org/2019/sqlite-autoconf-3280000.tar.gz
tar zxvf sqlite-autoconf-3280000.tar.gz
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

We've installed to the latest version, but the problem is same. Here,

```py
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.7.17'
```

In the [article](https://number1.co.za/upgrading-sqlite-on-centos-to-3-8-3-or-later/), they've mentioned about `LD_RUN_PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` paths.

> Then make sure to compile python again using the `LD_RUN_PATH` environment variable.
> It is better to use this variable over `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.
> Using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` - whenever python is run it will look for linked libraries with that path.
> What we want is for the libraries to be cooked into python at link time - compile time.

So based on the [article](https://number1.co.za/upgrading-sqlite-on-centos-to-3-8-3-or-later/), we can do the similar thing,

```sh
cd /opt/Python-x.y.z
LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib  ./configure
LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib make
LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib make altinstall
```

Then try again,

```py
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.31.1'
```

Here we go, one thing they've mentioned,

> If you do not use LD_RUN_PATH, then you have to make sure that the LD_RUN_PATH environment variable is set to /usr/local/lib for every user that is going to run python - which can be really annoying to do.

---

- **[testing a Django 2.2 website with SQLite3 on CentOS 7](https://www.djaodjin.com/blog/django-2-2-with-sqlite-3-on-centos-7.blog.html)**

This is same as the previous one and based on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` approach. Here is the steps from the [article](https://www.djaodjin.com/blog/django-2-2-with-sqlite-3-on-centos-7.blog.html),

```sh
$ wget https://www.sqlite.org/2018/sqlite-autoconf-3240000.tar.gz
$ tar zxvf sqlite-autoconf-3240000.tar.gz
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
$ make
$ sudo make install
$
$ python3.6 -c "import sqlite3; print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)"
3.7.17
$
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
$ python3.6 -c "import sqlite3; print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)"
3.24.0
```

---

If the last two steps didn't work, please comment below with the error you got and I'll find another solution for you.

Comment: It is correct that the SQLlite version requirement did change in Django 2.2.x, but if someone is cloning a project they've already deployed elsewhere, simply installing Django 2.1.x instead of 2.2.x or greater isn't going to help them at all if their project needs 2.2 or greater. Also, 2.1 is now end of life.

Comment: The last step was working for me. Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome @ManzurulHoqueRumi, glad to hear that.

Comment: Hi, I am using a version of python installed with brew for linux. Do you happen to know how to implement this solution there?

Comment: Option 2 worked like a charm for me to install Python version 3.9.6 from sources on an old Mac OSX 10.9 machine. Adding this comment, just in case it helps anyone coming here from Mac

Comment: @Wold I didn't work with brew, sorry. So which step you got stuck?

Comment: Glad to hear that @SarfraazAhmed!

Comment: I did `setenv LD_RUN_PATH "/mypath/sqlite/lib"`
`python -c "import sqlite3; print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)"` shows `3.29.0`
I am still hitting the error. Is there something else i need to check?

Answer (score 34):

I solved a similar situation with the following patches of code. Follow these steps that I used on my own centos7 & everything should be alright.
Just remember to let your centos7 know that you are calling `python3` not just `python` otherwise it will call the default python2 followed by a series of errors in your `virtualenv`.

Installing python3 (from source):

```
cd ~
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/Python-3.7.3.tar.xz
tar xJf Python-3.7.3.tar.xz
cd Python-3.7.3
./configure
make && make install
export PATH=$HOME/opt/python-3.7.3/bin:$PATH
```

Then run: `source .bash_profile`

Confirming by

```
python3 --version
Python 3.7.3
```

Installing your sqlite3 (from source):

```
$ cd ~
$ wget https://www.sqlite.org/2019/sqlite-autoconf-3290000.tar.gz
$ tar zxvf sqlite-autoconf-3290000.tar.gz
cd sqlite-autoconf-3290000

$./configure --prefix=$HOME/opt/sqlite
$ make && make install
```

Now this is what you should also remember to do for centos7 know where to look for your python3 and not defaulting to python2. On your `.bash_profile` copy & past this piece of code or edit the paths accordingly:

```
export PATH=$HOME/opt/sqlite/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/opt/sqlite/lib
export LD_RUN_PATH=$HOME/opt/sqlite/lib
```

Make it permanent by running: `source .bash_profile`
and you are done with `sqlite3 version >= 3.8`. Confirm it by:

```
sqlite3 --version 
3.29.0 2019-07-10 17:32:03
```

And then you can continue to use python3 to install python3 modules like django-2.2.

```
python3.7 -m pip3 install virtualenv

(myvenv37)[me@test my_project]$ python3.7 -m pip3 install django
Successfully installed django-2.2.3 pytz-2019.1 sqlparse-0.3.0
```

Remember, it is

`PYTHON3.7 -m pip3 install MODULE`

```
(myvenv37)[me@test my_project]$ python3.7 manage.py runserver
```

and the server should be running.

So, to conclude, in the case above it was `migrate`, & should look like this:

```
(venv)[me@test my_project]$ python3.7 manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 22):

As this was about Centos7, you can use the Fedora package to upgrade the Centos sqlite package:

```
wget https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/sqlite/3.8.11/1.fc21/x86_64/sqlite-3.8.11-1.fc21.x86_64.rpm

sudo yum install sqlite-3.8.11-1.fc21.x86_64.rpm
```

(from: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxadmin/comments/c9hy5w/trying_to_upgrade_sqlite_3717_to_version_38_on/ezrtbkm/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

This seems to work, although I'm never sure if doing this is really an ideal solution to a problem or not. I guess if you're not actually using SQLite, then this at least passes the version check and so gets you working.

Comment: The approach still only gets you to version 3.8, released in July 2015. It also doesn't work in the AWS Lambda Python container, if you're using that.

Answer (score 16):

[django 2.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.2/) need sqlite version >= 3.8.3

so the solution is **update your sqlite**:

1. download from [sqlite3](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html), select source_code version
2. tar -zxvf sqlite-xxx.tar.gz && cd xx
3. ./configure && make && make install
4. mv /usr/bin/sqlite3 /usr/bin/sqlite3.bak
5. mv xxx/sqlite3 /usr/bin/sqlite3
6. `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib"` and write it into ~/.bashrc

test1 :

```
sqlite3 --version
```

should be your version

test2:

```
$python
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
```

should be your version

Comment: Please specify the full path, I follow the instruction provided by you, after install where is the sqlite3, unable to find runnable sqlite3. Install cmd display below output  `Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/lib`
When I run `ls -l` on the above dir below files list out   
`libsqlite3.a
libsqlite3.la
libsqlite3.so -> libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
libsqlite3.so.0 -> libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
libsqlite3.so.0.8.6`. Please guide

Comment: did you do this?:`mv /usr/bin/sqlite3 /usr/bin/sqlite3.bak`

Comment: Can you explain step 6?  What is that doing?  And am I running that as a command and then copying it into bashrc?  What does the command do, and what does bashrc do?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and I struggled with it for a while. For me the best solution was to comment out DATABASES section in settings.py file.

As I don't want to use SQLite database then issue does not exist anymore. Later on you can update DATABASE information with the db that is valid for you.

Comment: Same here. SQLite seems to be the default "DBMS" for Django. If you are just setting up your project you can comment the section out as suggested and later on switch to a DBMS of your choice.

Comment: If you are going to use postgresql for the database, this seems like the simplest approach.

Answer (score 7):

You will only get make it worse with errors like multilib and other incompatibilities if keeps forcing the installation of sqlite 3.8.3 or higher. Just as @Theo also commented, the best approach is to comment the line #66 on the sqlite3/base.py (file within django) that triggers the method named ***check_sqlite_version()***.

This should just be warning that you are using a minor patch instead of raise an Exception (ImproperlyConfigured). You may also replace the raise with a print.

PD: Just make sure to comment it on the Virtual Environment and document it!

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I was having trouble with the above solutions on an Amazon Linux 2 instance and found that what was installed from my various attempts to update were causing version conflicts.
Initially I had this:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.9
$ python3
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.7.17'
>>> exit()
```

And `sudo yum install sqlite-3.8.11-1.fc21.x86_64.rpm` failed to install with this message:
[image: failed updated message]

I resolved it by the following steps:

`sudo yum list | grep sqlite`

These two packages were preventing updates due to conflict.
[image: grep list sqlite conflict]

`sudo yum autoremove sqlite-devel` To uninstall the extraneous package.

`sudo yum install sqlite-3.8.11-1.fc21.x86_64.rpm` To update the version.

`sudo yum list | grep sqlite`

New list of updated sqlite packages:
[image: grep list sqlite v2]

```
$ python3
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.8.11'
>>> exit()
```

Answer (score 5):

After few hours of searching I solved it using one command inside my virtual environment:

```
pip install pysqlite3-binary
```

You can check github [here](https://github.com/coleifer/pysqlite3) and article(a bit outdated) [here](https://charlesleifer.com/blog/compiling-sqlite-for-use-with-python-applications/).

I also found [here](https://gist.github.com/defulmere/8b9695e415a44271061cc8e272f3c300) that you should then place the following lines of code in your settings.py:

```
__import__('pysqlite3')
import sys
sys.modules['sqlite3'] = sys.modules.pop('pysqlite3')
```

but for me it worked without it.

Comment: I needed the import in settings. But this worked with Django 2.2

Answer (score 0):

another option is to use atomic repo

```
wget -O - http://updates.atomicorp.com/installers/atomic |sh
yum install  atomic-sqlite
LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/atomicorp/atomic/root/usr/lib64/' python3
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.8.5'
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question here: [ImproperlyConfigured('SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found %s).' % Database.sqlite_version)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60826836/improperlyconfiguredsqlite-3-8-3-or-later-is-required-found-s-database)

I solved this issue by upgrading my version of sqlite3 using this command:

```
cd ~ && wget https://www.sqlite.org/2020/sqlite-autoconf-3320100.tar.gz && tar xvfz sqlite-autoconf-3320100.tar.gz && cd sqlite-autoconf-3320100 && ./configure && make && make install
```

I am using ElasticBeanstalk for my setup, so I added a .config file to the .ebextensions folder and put this in it:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH: "/usr/local/lib"
commands:
  01_upgrade_sqlite:
    command: "cd ~ && wget https://www.sqlite.org/2020/sqlite-autoconf-3320100.tar.gz && tar xvfz sqlite-autoconf-3320100.tar.gz && cd sqlite-autoconf-3320100 && ./configure && make && make install"
```

Many thanks to Bejür for adding the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable here in order to get it to work.

Comment: I tried it with ec2 micro and  failed at ./configure step because no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH

Comment: @UMR Not sure what's going on with that then.  I've since given up on using SQLite in favor of using MySQL for everything instead.  I know this did work for me at the time though, but I was using Elastic Beanstalk with Amazon Linux, so maybe your environment is different that mine was.

Answer (score 0):

I make a fixed downgrade Django

```
pip3 install Django==2.1.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Another hacky way to solve it: build from source and replace lib files.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

RUN cd /tmp && \
    curl -L -O https://www.sqlite.org/2023/sqlite-autoconf-3410200.tar.gz && \
    tar -xzf sqlite-autoconf-3410200.tar.gz && \
    cd sqlite-autoconf-3410200 && \
    ./configure && \
    make -j$(nproc) && \
    make install && \
    cp /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so /var/lang/lib/libsqlite3.so && \
    cp /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0 /var/lang/lib/libsqlite3.so.0 && \
    cp /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 /var/lang/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 && \
    cp /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0 /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0 && \
    cp /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
```

Answer (score -2):

i had recently same problem
My solution was to change source code site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py line around 68 So far no side effects.

def check_sqlite_version():
if Database.sqlite_version_info < (3, 7, 3):
raise ImproperlyConfigured('SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found %s).' % Database.sqlite_version)

Comment: Hi. There is very good reason why someone decided to **disable** older version, as it don't support all operations.

Comment: For someone a reason may be exist, but not the error. This is the best approach! Just make sure to document it.