# Problem upgrading Sqlite3 version on CentOS for Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, sqlite, centos

I have `CentOS 6` on my system and I'm trying to update SQLite for Python. I've installed it from source and executing `sqlite --version` returns version `3.33.0` as expected.

However, when I try to check the python SQLite version using `import sqlite3; sqlite3.sqlite_version;` I still get the previous SQLite version `3.6.20`.

```
Software Locations:
     Python 3.6.9 - /usr/bin/python3
     Sqlite3 - /usr/bin/sqlite3
```

I've tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49920444/upgrading-sqlite3-version-used-in-python3-on-linux), this does not work at all, after updating `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and checking the python SQLite version it still gives '3.6.20', and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57532341/python-3-7-4-not-using-sqlite-3-29-0), when I try `sudo LD_RUN_PATH=`, it gives me the error `No such file or directory`, but when I execute it without sudo `LD_RUN_PATH=`, it successfully compiles but still gives me SQLite '3.6.20' (Compiled python without uninstalling).
[image: changing LD_LIBRARY_PATH]

Note: I have multiple python3 versions.

[image]

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Can you go to `/usr/bin/python3` and run `sqlite3 --version`?

Answer (score 0):

When I did it (specifically trying to find a way to update sqlite3 for a running python program; did not work...), I compiled sqlite and got libsqlite3.so.0.8.6, and then replaced the system-wide sqlite3 with that. For me on debian, that was in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu. I did see (though now I can't find where) that this way *may* cause issues when updating in the future. It did update python's sqlite3 for me though.

Answer (score 0):

You can import specific versions:

```
__requires__= 'sqlite3==3.6.20'
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.require("sqlite3==3.6.20")
import sqlite
```

Note that this only works on the first import. If sqlite gets imported before pkg_resources, it will take the latest version.